# How do I reexport qualified imported modules?

Tags: haskell, module, export

How can I reexport qualified imported modules in haskell? It is possible?

**Example:** I have two files. The file `Utils.hs` with the code:

```
module Utils (...) where

import qualified Data.Map as Map
```

and the file `main.hs`:

```
import Utils

main = putStrLn $ show $ Map.fromList [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

What do I have to put instead of `...` in the file `Utils.hs` so that the above file compiles and prints `fromList [(1,2),(3,4)]` to the standard output?

**Goal:** After importing `Utils.hs` in another file via `import Utils` I want to have access to the functions and types of `Data.Map` with the code `Map.<function or data name>`, i.e. so that with writing `import Utils` I do not have to write `import qualified Data.Map as Map` any more. Is this possible?

**Note:** There is a similar question at [Haskell re-export module in addition to everything defined within module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035458/haskell-reexport-everything). Unfortunately the answer does not help in this situation.

**What I tried so far:** The following code

```
module Utils (module Map) where

import qualified Data.Map as Map
```

compiles, but I get the error `` main.hs:3:26: Not in scope: `Map.fromList' `` if I try to compile `main.hs`.

Comment: Export qualified modules is impossible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207647/ghc-refuses-to-export-qualified-modules

Comment: @user2407038: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately I could not find the solution (see my extended question). Can you provide a running example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're asking for is not possible. `Map.fromList` will resolve successfully only if there's an import of the form

```
import [qualified] Map
```

or

```
import [qualified] ... as Map
```